# Find and replace column name with the match from the find

Tags: r

I'm trying to rename my columns in the dataframe called totsMerge

I need to find any string in the existing column name that lies between _TCO then two digits then a further _ eg *TC017* or *TC034*
I then want to replace the existing column name (there are characters in the name after this match) with the match.
I tried using the $1 for the match but it replaces the match literally with this
How can I replace the column name with the match from that column name?

```
  names(totsMerge) <- gsub("(_TC0.+?_)",'$1',names(totsMerge))
```

For example I would like to change the column names

```
 SLX.9397._HGD_TC070III_E_FLD0252.Read1_SND_QHGD_Apos.fq.gz
```

to

```
 TC070III
```

Comment: I have added an example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 sub('.*?_(TC0\\d{2}[^_]*).*', '\\1', str1)
 #[1] "TC070III"
```

Or

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract(str1, 'TC0\\d{2}[^_]*')
 #[1] "TC070III"
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- 'SLX.9397._HGD_TC070III_E_FLD0252.Read1_SND_QHGD_Apos.fq.gz'
```

Comment: I'm wondering why OPs code didn't work. For instance, `str_extract(str1, '(_TC0.+?_)')` will almost give the desired result, why didn't it give same output with `sub("(_TC0.+?_)",'\\1',str1)`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think one reason is that it may not match with the beginning of the string as `_TCO.` is not the starting character. and second `.+` can also include `_` where there are multiple `_`. while this works `sub(".*?(_TC0[^_]*_).*",'\\1',str1)` with the `_` at either ends.

Comment: @DavidArenburg It matches correctly for extracting, but for replacement it fails.  Using the `str_replace`, `str_replace(str1, '(_TC0.+?_)', '\\1')` Another less complicated example is `v1 <- c('_TC01113D_25', '125_TC0111_25'); sub("(_TC0.+?_)",'\\1',v1)`

Comment: This is strange to me because I always thought that `\\1` is for extraction. Though I don't understand why something will work for extraction but not replacement with the same regex.

Comment: @DavidArenburg We are capturing the group, but we are not removing the remaining part of the string.  A slightly different example is showed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787753/r-gsub-and-capture